# WCF WebService certificate not found on production server

Tags: web-services, wcf, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, wcf-security

I'm using custom authentication with a WCF Webservice. I created a local certificate on my computer, when I reference it in my web.config everything work.

On the production server, I created an SSL certificate and bind it to my website. The certificate is called "GAAWEBDEV_20Mars2020".

When I publish my application, this message is shown :

```
Cannot find the X.509 certificate using the following search criteria: StoreName 'My', StoreLocation 'LocalMachine', FindType 'FindBySubjectName', FindValue '‎‎GAAWEBDEV_20Mars2020'.
```

This is the code that I have in my web.config :

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Behavior1">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>   
        <!--
          <serviceCertificate findValue="Test" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
          storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        -->
        <serviceCertificate findValue="‎‎GAAWEBDEV_20Mars2020" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
         customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="PSA904.CustomValidator, PSA904" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="Behavior1" name="PSA904.servPSA904">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
     contract="PSA904.PSA904" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

This is the link of our website : https://psa904webdev.gaa.qc.ca/servPSA904.svc You can see that we have a certificate called "GAAWEBDEV_20Mars2020"

Thank you !

Comment: Could you maybe using the certificate in a wrong way?....SSL certifcates would be defined on the website in the binding location on the site?

Comment: also when using SSL with a certificate, your security mode should be MessageWithTransportCredentials

Comment: I changed to MessageWithTransportCredntials. I also defined the binding on the website with my certifcate "GAAWEBDEV_20Mars2020" but on web.config, I can't find the certificate

Comment: what do you use the certificate for? if you bind to normal ssl there should be no need to define certificate in your service Model element, unless you use the certificate for something else.

Comment: When I don't use the certificate, it shows this error : an error occurred when verifying security for the message

Answer (score 0):

First, Make sure that your certificate is exist. by Run certmgr.msc or mmc.exe.
also you can find certificate With other methods, For instance by thumbprint like this:

```
    <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" 
             x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" 
             findValue="14 c2 b1 c2 b8 a1 fd 25 n2 bb 39 5d 32 r3 53 f3 0c vy t1 c4"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your certificate is properly installed in the certificate store.
Don’t forget to assign the certificate store location. **storeName="My"**

```
<serviceCertificate findValue="‎‎GAAWEBDEV_20Mars2020" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" storeName="My" />
```

These are its enumeration values.
[image]
It corresponds to the following values in the certificate manager.
[image]
You can check with the certificate manager to see if the certificate has been properly installed. The way to open the certificate manager.

> Win+R>certmgr.msc

Please let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: My certificate exist in "Console Root > Certificates > Personal > Certificates" I don't know why my webservice don't find it

Comment: you could try to use the certificate's thumbprint to set up instead of the Subject.
<serviceCertificate x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" findValue="7d0d0ab6c6d4d4c533a84728b75796ea7dc3ddef" />. The certificate's subject and thumpprint can be found in the certificate's properties.

Comment: Friendly name not equal to the subject of the certiifcate. Double-Click the certificate and check the Details column.

Comment: When I use "FindByThumbprint", It shows me this error : "Invalid hexadecimal string format". When can I find the value that equals to friendly name ?

Comment: Do you have checked the certificate details? you can find the friendly name column in the Details menu. this is done because it may contain the same friendly name, but does not contain duplicate thumbprint. you should use the thumbprint of your certificate to search for the personal certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try, run the following code and see if your particular certificate appears

```
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My,StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                var certificates = store.Certificates;
}
```

You can use the certificates object to list all the certificates in a specific store, check from that output if your certificate exists.

You can also use the certificate object here to get your ThumbPrint, etc. As a last resort, you can try installing the certificate via code and using the same certificate to configure your webconfig either using xmlSerializer or Linq.